# Valgrind: Invalid read of size 1 (strtok, atoi)

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind

I'm having an issue with valgrind: This is my program (well the main part where the errors appear):

```c
static void leerLinea(u32 *a, u32 *b, FILE *file) {
    char *linea = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;

    linea = readline(file);
    token = strtok(linea, " ");
    free(linea);
    linea = NULL;
    while (!strcmp(token, "c")) {
        linea = readline(file);
        token = strtok(linea, " ");
        free(linea);
        linea = NULL;
    }

    if (!strcmp(token, "p")) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *a = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *b = atoi(token);
    } else if (!strcmp(token, "e")) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *a = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *b = atoi(token);
    }
}
```

And when I run valgrind it says:

```
Invalid read of size 1
at 0x4905E72: strtok_r (strtok_r.c:49)
Address 0x4a42b12 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 128 free'd
```

I can't figure out what's the matter with this program.

Comment: `if (!strcmp(token, "p")) { token = strtok(NULL, " ");` That `strtok` will be operating on `linea` which has already been freed.

Comment: So where can i free "linea" ? If i just free "linea" at the end still have 2 leaks.

Comment: You allocate `linea` twice and free it while still in use. You also need to handle the second `alloc`/`free` properly.

Comment: the function: `readline()` has the syntax: `char * readline (const char *prompt);` and the posted code is calling it as if its' syntax were: `char * readline( FILE * )`  which is not correct

Comment: Here is the MAN description for `readline()`  *readline will read a line from the terminal and return it, using prompt
       as a prompt.  If prompt is NULL or  the  empty  string,  no  prompt  is
       issued.  The line returned is allocated with malloc(3); the caller must
       free it when  finished.   The  line  returned  has  the  final  newline
       removed, so only the text of the line remains.*

Comment: regarding: `token = strtok(linea, " ");
    free(linea);
    linea = NULL;
    while (!strcmp(token, "c"))`  since the original memory allocation has been passed to `free()` any accessing of the memory, thereafter, is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must delay freeing the memory until you don't use the memory any longer. This includes calls to `strtok` and the tokens returned as well.

You could try something linke this (not tested):

```
static void leerLinea(u32 *a, u32 *b, FILE *file) {
    char *linea = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;

    linea = readline(file);
    token = strtok(linea, " ");

    while (!strcmp(token, "c")) {
        free(linea);
        linea = readline(file);
        token = strtok(linea, " ");
    }

    if (!strcmp(token, "p")) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *a = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *b = atoi(token);
    } else if (!strcmp(token, "e")) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *a = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *b = atoi(token);
    }
    free(linea);
}
```

Note:
This code does not include any checks for return values just as it just demonstrates how to modify the code from the question.

The return value of `strtok` should be checked for `NULL` values before feeding into `atoi` or other functions to avoid undefined behaviour

Comment: It would be advisable to check the return values of `strtok()` to avoid undefined behavior if the parsing fails.

Comment: I agree. But I assume that was a reduced example to demonstrate the error and i only addressed the valgrind issue. I'll add some note though.